# PowerShell select-xml xpath doesn't seem to work

Tags: xml, sharepoint, powershell, select-xml

I'm trying to use `select-xml` to root out a few things from a SharePoint solution.  I have a solution directory that contains a number of features, and rather than open each `feature.xml` and select names of features by hand and put them in a list, I was hoping to do the equivalent using `powershell` and `select-xml`.

My attempt went something like this:

```
ls -recurse -filter feature.xml | select-xml "/Feature"
```

and I got nothing, so I tried this:

```
ls -recurse -filter feature.xml | select-xml "//*"
```

which seemed to do what it was supposed to do.  I got a list of every XML node in all the feature.xml files in my solution.

I tried XPath expressions like "//Feature" and "Feature", none of which got any results.

It seems to me that my XPath expressions are right, but the behavior of select-xml is a bit bewildering.  Anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: If your "feature.xml" follows [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms475601.aspx) documentation, you should use a prefix bound to the namespace URI `http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/` for that QName test. Otherwise: `//*[local-name()='Feature']`

Comment: @Alejandro: the feature xml just has an attribute xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/".  I'm no expert, but doesn't that set the default namespace?  I thought if the default namespace was set, XPath would not need an additional specification for it.

Comment: No. That is a FAQ: a QName test without prefix selects element under null (or empty) namespace URI.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe the issue is with the xml namespace. Try using the [-namespace](http://huddledmasses.org/xpath-and-namespaces-in-powershell/) to get the correct xpath query.

Test this by removing the xmlns from a feature.xml file and running your command.

Comment: +agreed... i was going to post a comment asking about the namespace of the xml

Answer (score 11):

Even a "default" namespace has to be specified to Select-Xml e.g.:

```
$ns = @{dns = 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/'}
ls . -r feature.xml | Select-Xml '//dns:Feature' -Namespace $ns
```

Comment: If I use the default namespace `xmlns`, this is problematic because powershell indicates that one is reserved.

Comment: Even elements in the default namespace have to be qualified in your XPath expression.